# PHPExcel show and sum times

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm getting some times from my Postgres DB as string, for each record as give below:

```
11:58:00
-14:25:00
02:16:00
01:42:00
00:13:00
06:18:00
```

I'm trying to format as a custom time ([HH]:mm:ss) in when I export a excel file and sum this times in the end of lines.

But when I export a Excel file it's formatted as General format and can't sum this values.

I'm using PHP 5.4 and PHPExcel 1.8 version.

Comment: How are you setting these values in the worksheet? As strings? Or are you converting them to MS Excel serialized timestamps that can be formatted and summed?

Comment: @MarkBaker In the query I set these as time and when In phpexcel file I set this directly `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$line, $row[9])` or using `setFormatCode("[HH]:MM:SS")` and `setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4 )`

Comment: No, you're not setting them as a time in any format that MS Excel will understand.... what is the actual value of `$row[9]`? what datatype is it? Is it a string or is it a float? From your original question, it's a string... you need to convert it to an MS Excel serialized timestamp, which is a float

Comment: @MarkBaker So in the query I calculated this value like this `SELECT coalesce(SUM(time1::time),'00:00:00') - coalesce(SUM(amount) * ('08:48:00'::time),'00:00:00') AS sum_hours` returning me a interval value, but when the php takes this value I think it is a string type. So how can I convert it to an MS Excel serialized timestamp??

Comment: If the resultant value fetched to PHP in `$row[9]` is formatted as `hh:mm:ss`, then `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H' . $line, PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE($row[9]));` should convert that to a MS Excel timestamp value that you can then format using a mask of `'[hhh]:mm:ss'`

Comment: @MarkBaker to positive times, it works fine, but there are negative times that doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: How would you enter a negative time/duration in MS Excel itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128647/discussion-between-thiagofred-and-mark-baker).

Comment: @MarkBaker What position and how I set the MAC 1904 Calendar em my code? I found this `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::setExcelCalendar(PHPExcel_Shared_Date‌​::CALENDAR_MAC_1904)‌​` but I don't know how can I use and I didn't find anyone sample about this. Thanks

Comment: The question is why you need to set the calendar to Mac 1904? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @MarkBaker Because the problem with negative times was solved, setting 2 columns with the time values, then in another column I insert a formula as a Excel. So the calculation works, but there were cell results as a `############` that changed to `-14:25:00` when I set MAC Calendar in MS Excel.

Comment: That's a dirty workround, and probably wouldn't work in MS Excel on a Mac... but you set it by using the line of code that you quoted somewhere before adding iny data to your spreadsheet

Comment: @MarkBaker it doesn't work... it happens: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) in C:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\bi_web\rh\calculo_horas\consulta\excel.php on line 52`

Comment: So what's line 52? I can't see your excel.php script

Comment: @MarkBaker Could you see in the chat???